# Does the Subset Product Problem remain NP-complete if repetition in S is not allowed?

Tags: np-complete, decision-problem, subset-product

Just curioius, I wanted to know when $S$ ={set of divisors of N} and we're given $N$ a target product. Our goal is to decide if a combination in $S$ has product equal to N.

Does the problem remain NP-complete in this restriction? Assuming only positive integers?

Comment: Have you checked the original reduction? It might already have this property.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Apparently, so given the mathematical definition of set. Repetition isn't allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S = \{s_1,\dots,s_m\}$ (this is a multiset!), without loss of generality not containing any $1$s (if it does, remove them), and let $p_1,\dots,p_m$ be distinct primes which don't divide $N$ or any number in $S$. Let
$$ S' = \{ p_i, s_i p_i : i = 1, \dots, m \}, \quad N' = p_1 \cdots p_m N. $$

Suppose that there is a subset $T \subseteq S$ whose product equals $N$. Then the product of the following subset equals $N'$:
$$
\{ s_i p_i : s_i \in T \} \cup \{ p_i : s_i \notin T \}.
$$

Conversely, suppose that there is a subset $T' \subseteq S'$ whose product equals $N'$. By construction, $T'$ must contain exactly one of $\{p_i, s_ip_i\}$ for every $i$. If we let $T = \{ s_i : s_i p_i \in T' \}$, then the product of $T$ is $N$.

---

If we take the first $m$ primes larger than $\max(s_1,\dots,s_m,N)$ then the new instance has size polynomial in the size of the original instance. But it is not clear that we can find these primes efficiently. Therefore we need to slightly modify the construction.

Let $q_1,\dots,q_m$ be the first $m$ primes. We can find these in time $\mathit{poly}(m)$, which is polynomial in the size of the input. Now let $p_i = q_i^{e_i}$, where $e_i$ is larger than the total exponent of $q_i$ in all numbers in $S$ (we can find $e_i$ efficiently using GCD). The size of each $p_i$ is at most roughly the sum of sizes of the $s_j$, so this reduction can be implemented in polynomial time. Details left to you.